# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on linux 16.04

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and trying to start MySQL but I am getting this error. I also saw other solutions for same type of problem but still it is not working.
Here I tried entering my root password on Enter password prompt.

```
mysql -u root -p

Enter password: 

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Did you enter the password before hitting enter as the password prompt?

Comment: As the error message said you did not enter a password, Why?

Comment: _sorry yes you are right. First tried with root password and then with blank_ Not a very helpful description of your problem now is it

Comment: So show us the result when you enter your `root` password

Comment: Is this basically going to end up as a ___I forgot my `root` password question___

Comment: when i entered root password I am getting this error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
`

Comment: So you are entering the wrong password!!!

Comment: Or maybe you are trying to connect from another machine to a MySQL. Is that it?

Comment: But I am able get root access using `sudo -i` with my same root password so how can my password be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now my problem is solved i followed these things:

Stopped the MySQL service
    `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Start MySQL without a password
    `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

I got this error
    `2017-06-20T18:50:06.475664Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.`

used these commands to fix it:
    `mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld 
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`

then followed these commands:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
```

And it started working.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Now its working right but every time I restart my computer I need to follow this process again, can you plz tell how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the message `using password: NO` only appears if you simply press Enter instead of typing in the password.

Comment: sorry yes you are right. First tried with root password and then with blank

Comment: Can you please mark it, if it was a valid answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to MySQL at the moment but, if I remember correctly, if you don't have a password (which not a good idea), you simply don't use the `-p`.

Comment: Or you just hit Enter and leave the password prompt empty

Comment: I also tried this getting the same error. `mysql -u root` but this time error showing NO instead of YES